# How do I initialise a folder over ssh in git?

Tags: git, ssh

I want to push my local repository onto my web server **which does not have git** using ssh. Is this possible, or do you need a git repository such as github to do this?

I tried:

```
git init --bare ssh://user@host.com/public_html/test
```

Error message:

```
fatal: cannot mkdir ssh://user......../test/: Invalid argument
```

This error came before I even had to enter my password. The folder already exists.

But it didn't work. I can't find any information in the git book.

Comment: In what way did it not work? Did you get any kind of error message? And by folder, do you mean new repository?

Comment: @Trengot added the erorr message + info

Comment: Are you trying to put a bare repo on your webserver as a way to store your code to clone from elsewhere, or are you trying to use this to actually deploy your changes to the website? (The answer so far seems to presume the latter...)

Comment: @Wooble The latter is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have git on the server, once you have it installed, you'll access to the server and run (on the server):

```
git init --bare ~/repository.git
```

Then in your local git repository, you'll add a remote

```
git remote add origin user@host.com:~/repository.git
```

If you not have a local git repository created, you only need to clone it and you can start to use and make push / pulls to origin

```
git clone user@host.com:~/repository.git
```

And push the master branch (or what you want) to it:

```
git push origin master
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Using the git init --bare on your computer you'll only create a git repository inside a folder called `ssh: / user@host.com / pubic_html / test` and maybe Invalid argument for mkdir is a folder with `:`. I'm not sure on the last.

Comment: You could also login to the server and use "git clone --bare ssh://<address of local repo>" to save the need to initialise and then push to it to get the changes.

Comment: Yes but you need to have git on the server. If not, I think that is imposible. (I'm not a expert)

Comment: You need git on the server anyway to push/pull to/from it. If you don't it complains of "git-upload-pack" not found and similar errors.

Comment: Otherwise, I time ago I've use my dropbox local folder as a "remote" repository but i've create repository locally on the dropbox folder. Dropbox only sync the contents when I make a push. So if you can't install git on your server and want's a free and not public solution can do this or create a bitbucket account (github is only free for opensource). Regards!

Comment: There are problems using dropbox for hosting git repositories if you have multiple users pushing to them. Dropbox has its own version tracking system and will not merge two different versions of the file history if two users push to their local dropbox folders.

Comment: Nice point. Of course I have no team `:(` I do it only for version managing hehe.

Comment: According to [this](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#The-SSH-Protocol) I can clone a git repository over ssh. Is this a unidirectional thing, unless the server has git?

Comment: This article said that you can clone the git repository from the server and work with it using ssh protocol but, you'll need to create it before and for create it you'll need git.

Comment: You can use that command while working on the server (via ssh) to clone from your local repo but in that case your computer is acting as the server and (confusingly) your server is acting as the client.